# Is there a way to get the position of an element in Angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a problem:
I want to get the position of an element as values. Like x= 10 and y = 30 for example. After that i want use them to update the position of the element next time. Like first of all element A was on position x=5 and y=5. Then i drag the position and get the positions x=10 and y=30. Then i'm setting the position for the next time and update the position.
Please Help!

Comment: You can get element positon using plain JS. There are multiple ways to do that. E.g. using Element.getBoundingClientRect().
[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [an example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jf7c4k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-overview-example.ts) using `getBoundingClientRect()` to get all the data you need, and here is the code:

.ts :

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
  AfterContentChecked,
AfterViewChecked
} from "@angular/core";

/**
 * @title Basic Drag&Drop
 */
@Component({
  selector: "cdk-drag-drop-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "cdk-drag-drop-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["cdk-drag-drop-overview-example.css"]
})
export class CdkDragDropOverviewExample implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild("block") block: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}
  
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    let datas = this.block.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log("datas = ", datas);
  }

  onDrop(item: any) {
    console.log("item = ", item.target.getBoundingClientRect());
  }
}
```

.html :

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag #block (mouseup)="onDrop($event)">
  Drag me around
</div>
```

.css :

```
.example-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Note this is using cdkDrasg from Angular (I based the example from a stackblitz of the documentation) so you'll need to adapt a bit if you use something else for the drag & drop functionality.

Also, is you plan to edit the position manually (through typescript), consider using `Renderer2` instead of using the ViewChild directly.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer !!! :) yes im using the cdkdrag.  But the problem is now i get the values on the console right but i need them in a variable for example. Do you know how ?

Comment: @freeprogramming You're welcome. To get values in a vraible you can simply declare a new one under the viewChild in my example and set it when the values is updated. If you need to react to the changes you could use a `BehaviorSubject` from `rxjs`to push the new value inside and subscribe to it. If you don't know what it is I highly advice you to have a look at it, it's pretty useful :)

Comment: Thank you I did it and it works :) ! but there is still a last problem: im using more elements in a div with ngfor, i only get the position of the first element not the second .. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @freeprogramming I edited my code to use a `mouseup` event to get the current item and its datas. Now I highly recommand you to learn how to use the CdkDrag, it's pretty usefull  :) Consider tagging this answer as the correct answer and upvote it if it satisfy you :)